# DurandalJS - Switching from KO Templates to Compose

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I have a data table with two templates: *view* by default and *edit* if the item is selected. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to switch from KO's templates to Durandal's compose. Here's my current setup:

**View**

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: items }">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="template: {name: $root.itemTemplates}"></td>
      <td class="options">
        <ul>
          <li><a data-bind="click: edit">Edit...</a></li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script id="viewTemplate" type="text/html">
  <a href="" data-bind="text: name"></a>
</script>

<script id="editTemplate" type="text/html">
  <form class="edit" data-bind="submit: $root.save">
    <input type="text" name="name" data-bind="value: name, event: { keyup: $root.cancelEdit }" />
  </form>
</script>
```

**ViewModel**

```
self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

self.edit = function(item) {
  self.selectedItem(item);
}

self.itemTemplates = function(item) {
  return self.selectedItem() === item ? 'editTemplate' : 'viewTemplate';
}
```

Now I tried switching to compose by using `<td data-bind="compose: itemTemplates()"></td>`, but I noticed that my `itemTemplates` function stopped working properly, as it returns undefined for the `item` parameter. Also I noticed that when I hit `edit` now, it rebinds each item in my list, causing all of them to switch templates, instead of just the one I selected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure your views are each in their own file in the `views` directory, matching the names that your `itemTemplates` function returns. You may want to change the names to something more descriptive, but that's really up to you. Then, your binding should look like this.

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: items }">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="compose: { view: $parent.itemTemplates(), model: $data }"></td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The `view` property is necessary to control which view to use, without it the `viewLocator` will look for the matching view for the model, which is the view with the matching **name** by default convention.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I created the external templates and they load. My problem is with `itemTemplates`, the function that handles the loading of the templates. Instead of applying the change to just the item I selected, it changes all the items.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. I had to use `itemTemplates($data)` to get current item inside the template selector function. Thanks!